# passing parameters to .aspx page using renderpartial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

in my index.aspx page i want to render another module.aspx page using renderpartial
 which then render a .htm file 
depanding on which parameter is passed from index.aspx  (it would be number ie 1,2 etc ,so as to call different different .htm file everytime depending on the parameter)

1).
now i want Index.aspx page to render module.aspx and pass it a parameter(1,2,3,etc)
[the parameters would be passed programatically (hardcoded)]
and
2).
mudule.aspx should catch the parameter and depending on it will call .htm file

my index.aspx has

```
  <% ViewData["TemplateId"] = 1; %>
  <% Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/MyModule.aspx", ViewData["TemplateId"]); %>
```

and module.aspx contains

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Service.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">


        debugger;
        var tid = '<%=ViewData["TemplateId"] %>';

        $.get("/Templates/Select/" + tid, function(result) {
            $("#datashow").html(result);
        });



</script>

<div id="datashow"></div>
```

this is my controller which is called by $.get(....) (see code)

```
public ActionResult Select(int id)
    {
        return File("/Views/Templates/HTML_Temp" +id.ToString()+".htm" , "text/html");

    }
```

and finally
my .htm file

```
<div  id="divdata" class="sys-template">
<p>Event Title:<input  id="title"  size="150" type="text" 
        style="background-color:yellow;font-size:25px;width: 637px;"  
        readonly="readonly" value="{{title}}" />
    </p>   


<p>Event Description:<input type="text" id="description" value="{{ description }}"  
    readonly="readonly" style="width: 312px" /></p>

<p>Event Date: <input type="text" id="date" value="{{ date }}" readonly="readonly" 
        style="width: 251px"/></p>
<p>Keywords : <input type="text" id="keywords" value="{{keywords}}" readonly="readonly" /></p>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_init(appInit);
    function appInit() {
        start();
    }
</script>
```

start() is javascript  method which is in file Service.js

when i run this programm it gives me error
js runtime error: 'object expected'
and debugger highlighted on

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/**xhtml**1-strict.dtd">
```

pls help me solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you use [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962.aspx), you are by default passing the Model of your Index.aspx. Your partial view can then be of the same type. You can then use Model.MyParameter to find out which htm file you should be rendering. Otherwise you can pass it in the object parameter of the RenderPartial, and query that object inside of your partial view.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this `<% Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/MyModule.ascx", Model); %`> for passing the values using Model to a partial view MyModule.ascx. You can also use the method Html.RenderAction